# Access website through ssh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh

I am a poor web-dev beginner confused by kinds of web concepts :]
I want to setup a website on a server, either using rails or other framework. But I don't have full access to the server. I am wondering if this is possible?

**What I can do**

I can connect to the server through SSH, it means the port 22 is opened. And I can install packages with sudo privilege.

**What I want**

For example, I have a website built by rails and I want to make it run on the server.

**EDIT1**

Thanks for the answer but I want to run a website on the server that I can access it from somewhere else.

Comment: Then you should just be able to login via SSH and install Ruby and all of your Rails requirements. Once you have rails installed you can develop locally and transfer your files to the server using SCP or SFTP or painstakingly develop on the remote machine. Once you launch your web server it will be accessible on the port it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know a little more. Where is this Server hosted, who with and on what package?

What OS is the server running - installing Rails can be very easy - or hard depending on what you already have. For example

```
"sudo apt-get install rails"
```

will install rails, but it wont install a live server that you can run such as Passenger or Ngix.

It might be a lot easier to use someone like Engineyard who have a free trial you can use. They take care of all this for you!